# how to fetch only the newest rows from the model in django and show it as a table?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

**views.py**

```
 def inventory_display(request):
     if request.user.vendor == True and request.user.vendor_approval == True:
         vendor = CustomUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
         vendor_product = vendor.vendor_user.all()
         items = vendor_product[0].product_variants.all()
         return render(request, 'vendor/inventory_display.html',{'vendor_product':vendor_product, 'items':items})
```

Html

```
                   {% for product in vendor_product %}
                  {% for item in items %}
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">{{forloop.counter}}</th>
                      <td>{{product.created|date:"d-m-y"}}</td>
                      <td>{{product.edited|date:"d-m-y"}}</td>
                      <td>{{product.vendoruser}}</td>
                      <td><a href="{% url 'loomerang_admin:product_details' %}">{{product.product_id}}</a></td>
                      <td>{{item.item_num}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.variant_value}}</td>                       
                      <td>{{item.initial_stock}}</td>
                      <td>2</td>
                      <td>{{item.approval_status}}</td>
                      <td>{{item.approved_date|date:"d-m-y"}}</td>
                      <td>{{product.approved_by}}</td>
                    </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
              {% endfor %}
```

I am fetching data from 3 different models. I do fetch all the data from these models every time. What if I want to get the newest row only whenever the new row is added? I have included the User, Product, Productvariants models in the question.
I am showing data in the template by for loop. Without forloop i am getting repeated data in template, I want the latest data that will not exist in the template.

Comment: Show the model in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this field in your model

```
created_at          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

it will automatically add timestamp whenever object is created. and when you are geting objects
use this query

```
ModelName.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
```

Comment: I created `DateTimeModel` already and I inherited this to all the models I have. I am not getting the point, how to retrieve the new objects, whenever the new object is created.

Comment: okay then use  order_by('-created_at') or order_by('-id'). it will show data from newest to oldest

Comment: are you getting one object or list of objects? in case of single object use order_by('-created_at').first() or  order_by('-id').first()

Comment: really, I mixed up the objects were 3 different models. I moved the objects which I want to show to one model with the relationship. Finally, I get the output that I want. thanks for your answer.

Comment: great! glad it worked. you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

You can get the latest inserted item in multiple ways

**last() method**

```
vendor = CustomUser.objects.last()
```

**order_by() method**

```
vendor = CustomUser.objects.order_by('-id').first()
```

**latest() method**

```
vendor = CustomUser.objects.latest('id')
```

Comment: If we want to get the multiple objects, apart from `order_by()` which method do we use?. `latest(), last()` method returns a single object.

Comment: we can use `all()` for get all object which satisfy the conditions. Use `all()` along with `order_by()` fot get the multiple objects in a sorted manner

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the index number in your views:

```
def inventory_display(request):
     if request.user.vendor == True and request.user.vendor_approval == True:
         vendor = CustomUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
         vendor_product = vendor.vendor_user.all()[0] 
         items = vendor_product[0].product_variants.all()[0]
         return render(request, 'vendor/inventory_display.html',{'vendor_product':vendor_product, 'items':items})
```

And remove the for loop from the template:

```
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">1</th>
                  <td>{{vendor_product.created|date:"d-m-y"}}</td>
                  <td>{{vendor_product.edited|date:"d-m-y"}}</td>
                  <td>{{vendor_product.vendoruser}}</td>
                  <td><a href="{% url 'loomerang_admin:product_details' %}">{{product.product_id}}</a></td>
                  <td>{{items.item_num}}</td>
                  <td>{{items.variant_value}}</td>                       
                  <td>{{items.initial_stock}}</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>{{items.approval_status}}</td>
                  <td>{{items.approved_date|date:"d-m-y"}}</td>
                  <td>{{vendor_product.approved_by}}</td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: This gives an error `Product' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I have edited the answer check it out @sam